# Generate a matrix without 0 values in a random way

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to create a matrix in a random way in the intervals [-5,-1] and [1,5]. How can I create a matrix taking into account the intervals (no 0 values) with random values?

I tried to do it with `randint` of numpy and with `piecewise`. In the first case it is not posible to indicate 2 intervals and in the second case the random number generated when the value is close to 0 (bigger than -1 and lower than 1) is always the same.

```
    x=np.random.randint(-5,5,(2,3))
    np.piecewise(x, [x <= 1, x >=-1 ], [np.random.randint(-5,-1), np.random.randint(1,5)])
```

I would like to have a matrix in this way with no 0 values:

```
  [-2,-3,-1
    1,-2, 3]
```

Comment: Are you consider to use random.randrange( ... ) with some additional numpy array option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a random positive matrix and multiply it element wise by a random sign:

`np.random.randint(1,6,(2,3))*np.random.choice([-1,1],(2,3))`

Keep in mind that this only works if the interval is even around `0`, e.g. `(-6,6)` (`0` excluded).

Answer (score 7):

One option is to simply "remap" the value 0 to one of the bounds:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
x = np.random.randint(-5, 5, (4, 8))
x[x == 0] = 5
print(x)
# [[ 3  3 -2  2  2 -5 -1 -3]
#  [ 5 -3 -3 -3 -4 -5  3 -1]
#  [-5  4  1 -3 -1 -4  5 -2]
#  [-1 -1 -2  2 -4 -4  2  2]]
```

Or you can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
np.random.choice(list(range(-5, 0)) + list(range(1, 6)), size=(4, 8))
print(x)
# [[ 3  3 -2  2  2 -5 -1 -3]
#  [ 5 -3 -3 -3 -4 -5  3 -1]
#  [-5  1 -3 -1 -4  5 -2 -1]
#  [-1 -2  2 -4 -4  2  2 -5]]
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that the first solution makes the distribution non-uniform!

Comment: @fulaphex Does it? How so? Do not all 10 values have all the same probability of being chosen?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the bounds on the randint function. But I think there is still an error, I think it should be `x = np.random.randint(-5, 5, (4, 8))`. From the docs, the high value is one above the largest integer to be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.random.choice(list(range(-5,0))+list(range(1,6)),(5,5))
```

or

```
a = list(range(-5,6))
a.remove(0)
np.random.choice(a,(5,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(-5,6)
np.random.choice(list(numpy.select([a != 0, a == 0], [a, -1])),(5,5))
```

It's the other way where you can define your own condition of list. You can ommit whatever number from array 'a' you want by editing condition. In above on numbers equal to zero return -1 and for numbers non equal to zero return same number.

Comment: Thanks, but this only create a random number between intervals but I need a matrix